# How can I test my classifier for overfitting?

Tags: python, machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, classification, scikit-learn

I have a set of data in a .tsv file available [here](https://www.kaggle.com/c/stumbleupon/data). I have written several classifiers to decide whether a given website is ephemeral or evergreen.

Now, I want to make them better. I know from speaking with people that my classifier is 'overfitting' the data; what I am looking for is a solid way to prove this so that the next time I write a classifier I will be able to run a test and see if I am overfitting or underfitting.

What is the best way of doing this? I am open to all suggestion!

*I've spent literally weeks googling this topic and found no canonical or trusted ways to do this effectively, so any response will be appreciated. I will be putting a bounty on this question*.

Edit:

Let's assume my clasifier spits out a .tsv containing :

```
the website UID<tab>the likelihood it is to be ephemeral or evergreen, 0 being ephemeral, 1 being evergreen<tab>whether the page is ephemeral or evergreen
```

Comment: just gather enough more data (up to 30% amount of your original data) and run your classifier on it. If the performance is significantly lower than for your training set it's overfitting

Comment: @VsevolodDyomkin Thank you! So run the classifier on my test data, if it's getting 70% correct on that and it's getting 90% correct for my training data I am overfitting? Sorry, just clarifying before I run with that :)

Comment: Any classifier will perform extremely well on the training data. It's the accuracy over test data that you should focus on. Typically, a n-fold cross-validation is a good way to ensure there is no overfitting.

Comment: Make use of simple kernels, like linear kernel.

Comment: The simple definition of overfitting is that training error is (substantially) lower than test error. The answers are trying to tell you what to do about it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways that people try to handle overfitting:

- Cross-validation, you might also see it mentioned as x-validation

  - see lejlot's post for details
- choose a simpler model

  - linear classifiers have a high bias because the model must be linear but lower variance in the optimal solution because of the high bias.  This means that you wouldn't expect to see much difference in the final model given a large number of random training samples.
- Regularization is a common practice to combat overfitting.

  - It is generally done by adding a term to the minimization function
  - Typically this term is the sum of squares of the model's weights because it is easy to differentiate.
  - Generally there is a constant C associated with the regularization term.  Tuning this constant will increase / decrease the effect of regularization.  A high weight applied to regularization generally helps with overfitting. C should always be greater or equal to zero. (Note: some training packages apply 1/C as the regularization weight.  In this case, the close C gets to zero the greater weight is applied to regularization)
  - Regardless of the specifics, regularization works by reducing the variance in a model by biasing it to solutions with low regularization weight.
- Finally, boosting is a method of training that mysteriously/magically does not overfit.  Not sure if anyone has discovered why, but it is a process of combining high bias low variance  simple learns into a high variance low bias model.  Its pretty slick.

Answer (score 5):

The most simple way to check your classifier "efficiency" is to perform a cross validation:

- Take your data, lets call them X
- Split X into K batches of equal sizes
- For each i=1 to K:

  - Train your classifier on all batches but i'th
  - Test on i'th
- Return the average result

One more important aspect - if your classifier uses **any** parameters, some constants, thresholds etc. which are not trained, but rather given by the user you cannot just select the ones giving the best results in the above procedure. This **has to be** somehow automatized in the "Train your classifier on all batches but i'th". In other words - you **cannot** use the testing data to fit any parameters to your model. Once done this, there are four possible outcomes:

- Training error is low but is much lower than testing error - overfitting
- Both errors are low - ok
- Both errors are high - underfitting
- Training error is high but testing is low - error in implementation or very small dataset

Comment: I think one of the most damaging things with cross validation is people tend to use it in lieu of a development set. I.e. run cross validation, observe result, tinker with method, observe new result, etc. I suppose you could see 'method' as a parameter that's being tuned here; for this reason I think it's often better to have separate training, dev and testing sets unless you're constrained by data available.

Comment: Second to @lejlot. I am seeing nothing that could give this answer a downvoat.